# Jetty SSL problem after upgrade - unknown protocol

Tags: ssl, https, jetty, jetty-9

I upgraded Jetty 9.3.6 to Jetty 9.4.27 and I have a problem with SSL connection.

When I run curl on some supported operation I get
`error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (error 35)` whereas when I run the same command on the server running Jetty 9.3.6 it is all working fine.

I configured jetty's newer version in the same way as was the older one (including keystore path and enabling https support). Do you have a clue what could have gone wrong during upgrade or what I could have missed?

Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty 9.3.x and 9.4.x have different Cipher Suite exclusions.

Jetty 9.3.6.v20151106 looks like this ...

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.6.v20151106/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.java#L248-L260

```java
        addExcludeProtocols("SSL", "SSLv2", "SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3");
        setExcludeCipherSuites(
                "SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
                "SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
                "SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
                "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
                "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
                "SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
                "SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA");
```

Jetty 9.4.29.v20200521 looks like this ...

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.29.v20200521/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.java#L119-L138

```java
    /**
     * Default Excluded Protocols List
     */
    private static final String[] DEFAULT_EXCLUDED_PROTOCOLS = {"SSL", "SSLv2", "SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3"};
    /**
     * Default Excluded Cipher Suite List
     */
    private static final String[] DEFAULT_EXCLUDED_CIPHER_SUITES = {
        // Exclude weak / insecure ciphers
        "^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$",
        // Exclude ciphers that don't support forward secrecy
        "^TLS_RSA_.*$",
        // The following exclusions are present to cleanup known bad cipher
        // suites that may be accidentally included via include patterns.
        // The default enabled cipher list in Java will not include these
        // (but they are available in the supported list).
        "^SSL_.*$",
        "^.*_NULL_.*$",
        "^.*_anon_.*$"
    };
```

You'll want to evaluate why you need known vulnerable cipher suites to function.

Also, if you are using an IBM JVM all bets are off, because the IBM uses non-standard Cipher Suite names (unlike all other JVMs that use the RFC Registered Cipher Suite names).